# Spotify Api Results Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

In the image I have the code to display only the first element ( song, image , artist, etc ... ) .
I would like to know how to make it show me :

- When a user clicks on that button, show a new modal with all the
  results of the tracks search you performed previously.
- When a user clicks on one of the track names, update the player with
  that track's information, including its audio.

The button is already created.

```
$('#song_btn').on('click', function Search_Song (event) {
event.preventDefault();
var song = $('#song_input').val();
var request = $.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=' + song +'&type=track'); 
function Data_Songs (song) {
    var track = song.tracks.items[0];
    $('.song_title').text(track.name); 
    $('.artist_name').text(track.artists[0].name);            
    var cover = '<img src="' + track.album.images[0].url + '">';
    $('.cover_image').html(cover);
    var audio = '<audio class="js-player" src="' + track.preview_url + '">';
    $('.audio').html(audio);
    var more_results = '<br/><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="more_btn">Ver más Resultados</button>';
    $('.more_result').html(more_results);
};  
  function handle_Error () {
    console.error('¡¡ Ha Fallado !!');
  }
  request.done(Data_Songs);
  request.fail(handle_Error);
});
```

Comment: Please add the code as text and not as an image link. Take a look at [MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you already have it ;)

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like you have button to trigger the event...Here are your next steps:

1. Take an input (through a text field for example) and search for it through the API.
2. Next, obtain the parsed JSON from the API.
3. Then you'll be able to do what you are doing in your Data_Songs function...

Here's my implementation:

```
$('#song_btn').on('click', function(){
    var BASE_URL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/'
    var QUERY = $('#search_field').val(); // This is the value of your text field 

    var spotify_json = $.get(BASE_URL + 'search?type=track&query=' + QUERY, function(data){
        console.log(data.tracks); // Do whatever you want with them after here!
        // Ex. alert(data.tracks[0].href);
    })
})
```

Note that I used a success handler on the [$.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) method, which is a little different from your code.

To use your Data_Songs function in the $.get() function,

```
var spotify_json = $.get(BASE_URL + 'search?type=track&query=' + QUERY, Data_Songs(data));
```